# How to blend two transparent Images with Qt

Tags: c++, image, qt, qpainter, qimage

I have two rgb images and for each of the images a grayscale image. The grayscale images encodes the transparency of the two images per pixel, eg. black means not transparent, white fully. My question is: I want to merge the two images according to the transparency into one non-transparent image (if you sum up the two grayscale images you get black for each pixel). Any ideas on how to do this with qt 5?

Thanks!!

Comment: Ideas: 1) Load the 2 images and the 2 alpha maps as `QImage`s, modify the alpha channels in the two images according to the alpha maps, then blend normally. 2) As before, but just do Porter-Duff blending yourself using all four images as reference. 3) Play with `QPainter`'s composition modes -- if you're able to blit the alpha map, then a `SourceIn` or a `SourceATop` will give you the first image with a baked alpha, do the same with the second image, then blend them together in normal `SourceOver`.

Answer (score -1):

Convert your image to a `QPixmap` (using `convertFromImage`). Then use `setMask` with your grayscale bitmap as parameter. I haven't tested in Qt5 but it should do the trick.

Comment: No. `setMask` sets a monochrome mask and has nothing to do with blending, unless you harken back to the days where dithered monochrome X11 was all the rage.

Comment: My bad, only time I had to use it was for an all or nothing, no semi-transparent, solution.

Comment: I ended up doing in manually with setPixel. Probably not efficient but it suffices in my case.